# SQL query with regex

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have a table `vehicles` has a column 'name'

Values are stored like `car/tesla`, `car/honda`, `truck/daimler` (each value is stored as `type/brand`)

I want to query the table using only `brand`. If I look up `tesla`, it should return the row corresponding to `car/tesla`. How do I do it? I'm using `postgres`.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Please show your query. Why do you think a `LIKE` won't do?

Comment: Why regex when you only need `LIKE '%/tesla'` ?

Comment: In all honesty, that sounds like a database design that should be reconsidered - do NOT store multiple values in one field unless you have a very good reason for doing so.  And as some folks have indicated already, if you really have to do this, you can use LIKE.

Comment: I was stuck because I never had to use LIKE. Plus this is only a small part of a JOIN statement I am writing and the problem in the question is not exactly my real problem, I made it up so it will be easier to understand. Now I have enough info to get my thing correct. Thanks for helping.

Comment: If you have no control over the database, I would use a CTE to simplify (substring...) AS Type, (substring....) as Model - and then use a normal query thereafter (part of), to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need in regex in your case. Just use old good `like`:

```
select name
  from vehicles
  where name like '%/tesla'
```

Answer (score 1):

2 solutions are available a select query with LIKE operand or a select query with contains operand.

```
select * from vehicles where name LIKE '%tesla%'

Select * from vehicles where Contains(name, "tesla");
```